# Multiple compound words

Tags: hyphenation, compounds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect a word and a phrase with a dash?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/how-to-connect-a-word-and-a-phrase-with-a-dash)

Hello, I'm a non-native English speaker and I'm writing a scientific paper about biometric identification based on heart sounds.

In this context, is the following phrase correct?

> Comparison of recent articles on heart sounds-based biometrics.

I am using it as a caption for a table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct form would require another hyphen:

> Comparison of recent articles on
>   heart-sound(s)-based biometrics

However, such long compound adjectives are a bit ugly. Instead you could write this:

> Comparison of recent articles about
>   biometrics based on heart sounds.

Or perhaps this:

> Comparison of recent articles on
>   heart-sound biometrics

It seems clear that these biometrics are based on whatever word you use to specify them, which is why I suspect the word "based" isn't really necessary; or is it?

Comment: No, it isn't necessary at all. Many thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Could you kindly add a reference, so that I can cite this, Cerberus?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: See Fowler, as quoted in an answer to the question of which the above is a duplicate. Or do you want it in my answer? Then feel free to add it from there.