# Should "heavy-duty" always be hyphenated when used as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, punctuation, hyphenation, compound-adjectives

An example term: super heavy-duty construction

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113422/how-to-use-hyphens-appropriately-when-listing-multiple-hyphenated-terms https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15054/multiple-compound-words etc.

Comment: If you were asking ***Is** "heavyduty" always hyphenated?*, the answer would be [**No**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heavyduty+plastic%2Cheavy+duty+plastic&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheavyduty%20plastic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheavy%20duty%20plastic%3B%2Cc0). Whether it *should* be or not is a matter of opinion (but apparently Americans are more likely to discard the hyphen than Brits, according to that NGram).

Comment: The usual rule is to use a hyphen when the first adjective modifies the second rather than modifying the noun.

Comment: Thanks, @FumbleFingers and Carl
Would you agree that *heavy* is modifying *duty* in the example term, and therefore should be hyphenated?

Comment: @NRW: Don't ask me about what *should* happen in this context! In matters of orthography I'll agree with anyone that first-person ***I*** should be capitalised, or that people should write ***should*** rather than ***shud***, for example. But per the link in my first comment (posted to explain my "Primarily Opinion-based" closevote), as often as not your particular two words are concatenated without a hyphen in the very common collocation ***heavyduty plastic***. Choose whichever you like, but don't go thinking the alternative is "wrong". It's just that - an *alternative*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you mean by **should**.

From a grammatical point of view, no.

*From the point of view of making your writing clear — **yes**,* it is *not* a matter of opinion.

Why? To avoid what Fowler in [A Dictionary of Modern English Usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_Modern_English_Usage) called [false scent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_scent).

Simplifying by leaving out ‘super’, if I read:

> heavy duty construction

the first word I encounter is an adjective, ‘heavy’, and this is followed by a noun, ‘duty’, so — depending on the sentence — I may initially think that ‘duty’ is the operative noun, qualified by ‘heavy’. When I read the third word ‘construction’ I have to reset in my mind that ‘heavy duty’ is being used adjectivally to describe ‘construction’.

If I write:

> heavy-duty construction

there is no possibility of such ambiguity.

One could argue that ‘heavy duty’ is such a familiar grouping that it is unlikely to lead to ambiguity, but in general I would suggest it is better to make a habit of avoiding ambiguity rather than deliberating over the familiarity of each word combination. In the case where there is a preceding adjective it is certainly necessary to increase clarity. Thus in:

> extremely heavy duty construction

(I have replaced ‘super’ by ‘extremely’ — *see* footnote) one would read ‘extremely heavy’ as if the adjective just qualified ‘heavy’ and then have to perform a mental reset on seeing that it is meant to describe ‘heavy duty’. Again,

> extremely heavy-duty construction

has no such problem.

I would suggest finally that it is better to have a logical reason for hyphenation that you can remember and justify, rather than mindlessly trying to follow some ngram trend.

**Footnote on ‘super’**

I am not sure whether you are using ‘super’ as a simple adjective like ‘very’ or as a technical term as in ‘supersonic’. That is why I replaced it by ‘extremely’ in my example. You do not ask specifically about ‘super’, but if it were a technical or trade designation I would assume that it was in a late stage of amalgamation, having passed the (in this case) awkward hyphenation phase, and write it: ‘superheavy duty’, by analogy to [‘superheavy elements’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transuranium_element#Super-heavy_elements). As an adjectival phrase I would write ‘superheavy-duty construction’.