# low risk rating VS low-risk rating

Tags: hyphenation, modifiers

As I understand what is happening:

1. First, we have a **rating**.
2. Second, we modify it with an adjective, calling it a **risk rating**.
3. Third, we modify the adjective with another adjective, which is why we hyphenate it, resulting in a **low-risk rating**.

But, is it ok to not hyphenate it and call it a **low risk rating**.

My *feeling* is that you'd call it a **low-risk whatever** when you have varied descriptors such as: **low-risk**, **low-interest**, **high-volatility**; but when you are only talking about risk ratings, you'd leave out the hyphen. "Our optimal risk rating is a low risk rating." Because, now, the noun has become the **risk rating** as opposed to the **rating**. (I mean, cripes, should I hyphenate risk-rating?? So many bleeding hyphens!!!)

(I'm asking because Microsoft Word is giving me a *bunch* of hyphen suggestions and it's annoying the feck out of me.)

Comment: The main reason to hyphenate is clarity: You don't want the reader to read "Low (risk rating)," like me on a balmy day of rating risks.

Comment: @YosefBaskin But that's exactly how it's intended be read. A risk rating is a number, like 75% possibility of failure. A low value of this might be 10%.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should com­pound words be writ­ten as one word, with hy­phens, or with spaces?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-compound-words-be-written-as-one-word-with-hyphens-or-with-spac) Or [hyphenation of compounds with terms made of two words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/612754/hyphenation-of-compounds-with-terms-made-of-two-words/618705#618705)? A low risk rating defaults to a risk rating that is low; a low-risk rating is a rating of low risks.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Or a rating that has low risk. Neither of them makes much sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Compound modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier) (Wikipedia).  The general rule is that the hyphen should connect the pair of words which are more closely associated, so it's wrong in this case - we're not describing a **rating** that is **low risk** (compare "low-risk experiment", where the hyphen *is* appropriate), we're describing a **risk rating** that is **low**.

You could write **low risk-rating**, but that might come off as old-fashioned.  Omitting the hyphen altogether is probably the better solution.

Comment: Thanks. This is how I was thinking about it too, I just wanted to confirm it wasn't wrong to leave out the hyphen.