# Multiple hyphens in a word or 'word': are such assemblages acceptable?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Is it allowed to have multiple hyphens in one word? I want to use the word *semi-self-sustaining* in the sentence

> However, the ability to produce **semi-self-sustaining** stations is
>   possessed by up to a quarter of all nations.

Should we use *semi-selfsustaining* or avoid it by using *partially self-sustaining*?

Comment: The dash mark should be longer: "semi–self-sustaining". See http://english.stackexchange.com/a/380203/8278

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In ‘[The Penguin Guide to Punctuation’](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140513663), R L Trask identifies three cases in which a hyphen is required after a prefix. One of them is where a prefix is added to a word which already contains a hyphen. His examples are *non-bribe-taking politicians*, *his pre-globe-trotting days, non-stress-timed languages* and an *un-re-elected politician*.

In your example, *self-sustaining* is a word which already contains a hyphen and to which you wish to add the prefix *semi-*. The resulting *semi-self-sustaining* is consistent with Trask’s advice.

Comment: Do note that these forms are hard to parse and that people tend to avoid them. The google books search for Trask's examples give 5, 1, 8 and 0 results respectively, from the whole corpus.

Comment: @ Jasper: It's the only one most people need. I always try to recommend it whenever anyone mentions Lynne Truss.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, The dash mark should be longer: "non–bribe-taking", "pre–globe-trotting", "un–re-elected". See http://english.stackexchange.com/a/380203/8278

Comment: Using a longer dash is a matter of opinion: some style guides may like it but [others don't](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/HyphensEnDashesEmDashes.html) and IMO it looks horrible.

Answer (score 4):

I don't personally think that using multiple hyphens is a general problem. I have often seen words like "four-year-old" and the like to make an example.

Since self-sustaining is written with a hyphen, I would go for semi-self-sustaining.

Comment: isn't "four-year-old" an example where no hyphens at all were needed? eg "four year old" has the same (or clearer) meaning?

Comment: @oxinabox I usually see the hyphens when it's being used to modify a noun, like a four-year-old red wine.

Comment: I fail to see, how that is better than "four year old red wine"
Perhaps this merits a question in it's own right.

Comment: @LyndonWhite, The reader might need a double-take. Consider ""*I purchased four year old red wine bottles.*"", vs ""*I purchased four year-old red-wine bottles.*"".

Comment: Also  ""*I purchased sixty four year old red wine bottles.*"", vs ""*I purchased sixty four-year-old red-wine bottles.*"".

Answer (score 0):

*The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2010) glancingly affirms the advice that Barrie England cites from *The Penguin Guide to Punctuation* in his answer:

> **6.80 *En dashes with compound adjectives*.** ...
>
> A single word or prefix should be joined to a hyphenated compound by another hyphen rather than an en dash; if the result is awkward, reword.
>
> > non-English-speaking peoples
> >
> > a two-thirds-full cup (*or, better,* a cup that is to-thirds full)

As Chicago very wisely observes, the critical question to ask in deciding whether to use multiple hyphens in a compound word is a highly subjective one: Does the result seem awkward? If it does, your best bet is to reword to avoid the awkwardness—not to press on in unthinking obedience to some set-in-stone rule about proper punctuation, regardless of the effect it has on the sentence you're trying to construct.