# semi-business-related?

Tags: adjectives, suffixes, prefixes

I'm writing my statement of purpose for grad school application. I would like to express "I came from an academic background that is half business-related", as I majored in E-business. What is the correct adjective form in this case?

semi-business-related, semi-business related, semi business-related, or "semi" is not required at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple hyphens in a word](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46368/multiple-hyphens-in-a-word)

Comment: Surely 'business-related' is a binary adjective- something either is, or isn't related to business? So how can something be half (semi) related to business?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use *business-related*, just use that.  No *semi-* required. *Related* means:

> connected in some way ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/related))

E-business is definitely "connected in some way" to business, so just say,

> I came from an academic background that is business-related.

Or, even better,

> My academic background is business-related.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid trying to find the right hyphenated adjective as you've described it, and instead say something more simple and direct, such as, **"My academic background includes a major in E-business."**