# Correct usage of “all expenses paid”

Tags: word-usage, hyphenation

I am confused on how to properly describe an all expense paid vacation.

Is it an *all expenses paid vacation* or an *all expense paid vacation*, and are there any hyphens between all, expense or expenses, and paid?

I ask because it seems to be all over the place on google search.

Comment: On hyphenation (rather than singular-plural form), also see https://english.stackexchange.com/a/380203/8278

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“All expense paid” uses *expense* as a mass noun; “all expenses paid” uses *expense* as a countable noun. You would choose the one that is closest to your intended meaning.

As for hyphenation, you would typically use them when the phrase functions as an adjective, as in “all-expense[s]-paid vacation”.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the question asking for elaboration on "*closest to your intended meaning*"?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the first option: there are probably several expenses involvbed in your hollidays: restaurants, hotels, souvenirs etc.