# Non in front of hyphenated adjective

Tags: adjectives, american-english, hyphenation

If one wishes to add "non" in front of a hyphenated adjective, should one add a hyphen after "non?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect a word and a phrase with a hyphen?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/how-to-connect-a-word-and-a-phrase-with-a-hyphen)

Comment: Could you please provide an example? For example "Non wind powered renewable energy" Where would you place the hyphen(s)? (I'm not even sure that makes sense, I just made it up on the spot)

Comment: Most writers include ***two*** hyphens in, say, [***non-coal-fired**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22non+coal+fired%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) [power stations, etc.].*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chicago Manual of Style, 14th Edition, addresses this question indirectly in section 5.117:

> The en dash is also used in place of a hyphen in a compound adjective when one of the elements of the adjective is an open compound (such as *New York*) or when two or more of the elements are hyphenated compounds:
>
> New York–London flight
>   post–Civil War period
>   quasi-public–quasi-judicial body
>        *but*
>   non-English-speaking countries
>   not-to-be-forgotten moments

Since your usage is of the latter form (a normally hyphenated element in front of a hyphenated compound adjective), the use of multiple hyphens is therefore recommended:

> He was the only non-red-haired person in his entire family.

Answer (score 2):

"non" isn't a word, so you can't write this:

> non red-haired [noun]

This is less wrong, but I still don't like it:

> non-red haired [noun]

We've lost the link between "red" and "haired," so someone might interpret it as "hairy [noun] which is not red."

I like this form:

> non-red-haired [noun]

In this case, it's clear we're negating the entire adjective rather than just the color.