# Hyphenation of a word to a two-word phrase

Tags: punctuation, american-english, sentence, hyphenation

How should one treat the hyphenation of a word to a two-word phrase, such as in the example below:

> something about the qubit-**resonator mode** frequency detuning.

The sentence tries to express: "something about the frequency detuning of the qubit from a mode of the resonator," but in a succinct form. If we could only use the word by itself, this sentence would work, but **resonator** alone is not correc, it has to be qualified by the word mode, i.e. a mode of the resonator: hence, the single unit, **resonator mode**.

Comment: Well, *qubit resonator-mode frequency detuning* would make the most sense, as I read it.

Comment: Certainly since you are talking about the qubit of a resonator mode, it should be "qubit resonator-mode". What you have right now, "qubit-resonator mode", means you are talking about a mode of the qubit resonator. Which is not what you are talking about, so I don't understand why you're even considering it.

Comment: @RegDwight: the question is how to hyphenate things like Canada-United States treaty. It's a [duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/how-to-connect-a-word-and-a-phrase-with-a-hyphen?rq=1), and should be closed as a duplicate, and ***not*** as an unclear question.

Comment: This question was answered by Peter and the link he provided as well as Nonym, can we either delete it or unblock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with using

> something about the frequency detuning of the qubit from a resonator mode ?

I'm afraid that no matter how you hyphenate *qubit–resonator-mode frequency detuning*, it's not going to be comprehensible. It's a [noun pile-up](http://arnoldzwicky.org/2012/01/31/noun-pile-examples/), like *air bag malfunction safety recall follow-up notice*, and those should be avoided.