# non-administrator-level-user privileges or non-administrator level-user privileges?

Tags: punctuation

Please consider the two examples below. Which, technically, without rephrasing, is the correct choice?

1. ***non-administrator-level-user privileges***
   [Here the four-word compound adjective modifies "privileges".]
2. ***non-administrator level-user privileges***
   [Here "non-administrator-level" is the modifier of the hyphenated "user-privileges". Should "user-privileges" be hyphenated here, as a noun, when it follows the already-hyphenated "non-administrator-level"?]

Of course, we could truncate the phrase by deleting "level" and be left with "non-administrator-user privileges", which is, in my opinion, correctly punctuated (yes or no?) and probably the best option, no doubt. Agreed?

My question is whether or not 1 or 2 is the better punctuation choice. And why? Does each example have a different meaning because of the shift in hyphenation, or do they both have the same meaning?

Comment: Your 4th paragraph deletes "level" not "user"

Comment: Oops. Nice catch. That's what I meant. Didn't have morning coffee yet. I'll change it now

Comment: See e.g. *[How to connect a word and a phrase with a hyphen?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/how-to-connect-a-word-and-a-phrase-with-a-hyphen)*. Personally, in the absence of other context, I would truncate to *non-administrator privileges*, but that's just a matter of opinion.

Comment: I agree, choster. Less is sometimes more.

Answer (score 2):

The "user" belongs more with the "privileges" than it does with "level".

Therefore, if you are intent on using lots of hyphens, I would suggest this is more correct than either of your two alternatives:

**non-administrator-level user privileges**

*However* less can be more, so I would suggest:

**non-administrator level user privileges**

This is just as clear, perhaps more so, than any of the other options.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above.

Hyphenation is a matter of style.  So claiming correct or incorrect is a tad subjective.  However, there are rules for style if you choose to follow a manual of style.

[*The Chicago Manual of Style*](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf) has many hyphenation rules, many of which boil down to this:

> Adjective form hyphenated before but not after a noun.

So the answer depends on what you're trying to make into a noun.

1. is correct if `privileges` is your noun and the rest is your adjective.  However, level and user both seem redundant here and so should be removed.
2. has a typo.  The bracketed comments mention `non-administrator-level` but the bold text has no hyphen between `non-administrator` and `level-user`

2. in bold, is wrong because `level-user` is nonsense in this context.

2. in brackets, I decode your intent as:

> 2. **non-administrator-level user-privileges**

This would make sense if `non-administrator-level` was the adjective and `user-privileges` were a noun.  However, that would mean that `user` was a prefix (like non) and it's not.

I would reword it as

> non-administrator privileges

but since you refuse rephrasing try

> non-administrator level user privileges

Comment: While on the subject, should "peanut-butter-and-jelly sandwich", "ice-cream sandwich", "living-room furniture", "driver's-side door", and "passenger-side door" get hyphens as shown? Many thanks for your opinions.

Comment: I researched the above in The New Yorker, and they hyphenate all of them. Good enough for me! 