# How to spell correctly: "neutral-stability curve" or "neutral stability curve"?

Tags: orthography

I have a question regarding spelling the following phrase: "neutral stability curve" in the meaning of "curve of neutral stability". Should I put a hyphen between "neutral" and "stability" or not?

Is the rule on this different in American and British English?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect a word and a phrase with a hyphen?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/how-to-connect-a-word-and-a-phrase-with-a-hyphen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a compound noun (no hyphens), usually appearing as *the/a neutral stability curve*. It is used in naval architecture to depict an aspect of ship stability and also in a few other branches of fluid dynamics to delineate stable regimes of flow from unstable ones.

*Direct Numerical Calculations of a Neutral Stability Curve for One-Dimensional Detonations* by Wei Cai, Wonho Oh, and Youlan Zhu

*A neutral stability curve for incompressible flows in a rectangular driven cavity* by A. Abouhamza and R. Pierre

*Neutral stability curves for a thermal convection problem Part II. The case of multiple solutions of the characteristic equation* by A. Georgescu, I. Oprea

Comment: Thank you very much, Phil! I didn't think about this as a compound noun! I was thinking about 'neutral stability' as a modifier of 'curve', therefore, was inclined to spell it with a hyphen. However, in the literature they do not put a hyphen there; that's why I've asked my question.

Answer (score 1):

- Is it a curve that has or expresses **neutral stability**? If so: "*neutral-stability curve*".
- Or is it a **stability curve** that is neutral? If so: "*neutral stability curve*".

You say that it is a "*"curve of neutral stability*", so you would use the first of these - hyphenate.

The point of joining "*neutral*" and "*stability*", in "*neutral-stability*", is to apply the compound adjective of neutral stability to the curve.  The point of not joining them is to apply "*neutral*" to a stability curve, that is, apply "*neutral*" to the application of "*stability*" to "*curve*".

This is a general rule that you can often use to increase clarity. But it is often not followed, and there are no doubt exceptions where it might even reduce clarity. A lot can depend on whether the compound adjective really make sense - e.g., whether there is such a quality as "*neutral stability*".

Comment: The general rules-of-thumb for hyphenating compound pre-modifiers have been covered before, and you don't address the actual example (which Cathy Gartaganis does).

Comment: It is neither of those two things. It is a particular thing, not a type of thing. It separates regions of positive and negative stability in fluid dynamics stability analysis.