# How do I write "something-based", where "something" is more than one word?

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

I want to write "unsupervised learning based method", where "based" is referring to unsupervised learning. That is, it's (unsupervised learning)-based method, not unsupervised (learning-based methog). How do I write this? Maybe "unsupervised-learning-based method"? Is there a way of paraphrasing it that sounds better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to hyphenate with compound premodifiers? If so, where is the hyphen placed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/is-it-correct-to-hyphenate-with-compound-premodifiers-if-so-where-is-the-hyphe) Your doubly hyphenated form is correct, although some style guides like to complicate things with a mixture of hyphens and dashes to indicate degrees of cohesion. // It _sounds_ reasonable, as 'hyphen' isn't pronounced.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your great-help--providing answer! :)

Comment: I would suggest "Autonomous Learning" Studies suggest that students taught methods for autonomous learning have a greater probability of succeeding in a high school setting. Further, students screened for their level of autonomous learning perform better than those advanced simply on scholarly achievement

Comment: @nim.py Note that a stylistically more elegant method is sometimes to use an en dash. This is appropriate when an open compound is used as part of an adjectival phrase and you don't want to hyphenate it. So: *it's an **unsupervised learning–based method**.* (Anybody with a keen eye will spot the difference between - and –.) However, while this is what's suggested by major style guides, it might not be immediately obvious to everybody.

Comment: @user387838, unsupervised learning is a term with a specific meaning (in the context of deep learning / AI), so I wouldn't be able to use autonomous learning instead.

Comment: @JasonBassford yeah, as you point out, I think it wouldn't be obvious to everybody. For the moment, I am going with "unsupervised-learning--based".