# Hyphen use: convention for made-up words with a compound noun or phrase?

Tags: punctuation, word-usage, hyphenation

Apologies for the verbosity of the title. Example: "morse code speak". What should be hyphenated and what not?

Facing this, I had informally adopted the practice of enclosing the compound noun/phrase with inverted commas ('), before treating it as one word and adding a hyphen. i.e.

> 'morse code'-speak
> 'search engine'-cum-wikipedia
> 'civilised society'-influenced

Comment: The second part of this question has been removed as it's [already been asked](/questions/80520).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to hyphenate with compound premodifiers? If so, where is the hyphen placed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/is-it-correct-to-hyphenate-with-compound-premodifiers-if-so-where-is-the-hyphe)