# Should a two-word noun that modifies be hyphenated?

Tags: adverbs, hyphenation, compound-adjectives, adverbials, adverbial-phrases

I came across the sentence "He is Fibonacci spiral attractive," and my first thought was that "Fibonacci spiral" should be hyphenated. I consulted my sister, and she thought it should be "Fibonacci spiral-attractive." Now I'm considering that I'm wrong about it needing any hyphen at all.

I've been scouring the internet for answers, but I don't really know the technical terms, so I haven't been very successful.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  Does this related question help?  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/is-it-correct-to-hyphenate-with-compound-premodifiers-if-so-where-is-the-hyphe

Comment: Sort of. The question is pretty much exactly what I'm asking, but people seem divided on the answer there, and I feel like some of the suggestions in the top answer are completely wrong and inconsistent. Thank you for the link!

Comment: Welcome indeed! Could you [edit your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/556367/edit) (a) to explain why the earlier question doesn't help [be specific] and (b) to explain what your three-word phrase actually means, as adding a hyphen in the wrong place could change its meaning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to hyphenate with compound premodifiers? If so, where is the hyphen placed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/is-it-correct-to-hyphenate-with-compound-premodifiers-if-so-where-is-the-hyphe)

Answer (score 2):

There is a probable duplicate, but I've never seen this (doubtless nonce) compound secondary-modifier (adjective modifier, traditionally *adverb*) before.

**Fibonacci∞spiral∞attractive**.

Where if anywhere does one hyphenate?

Looking for similar strings that *are* idiomatic, we find

- *drop-dead gorgeous* and   arguably
- *lead-pipe cinch* but
- *stone cold sober* as well as *stone-cold sober*.

The latter is probably *so* idiomatic that a hyphen is felt to be unnecessary clutter. Practice may also vary with position of modifier (prenominal or predicative).

With the nonce candidate here, there is obviously a possibility of confusion, one factor being the unusual reference (a Fibonacci spiral). (Actually, the golden spiral looks more perfect ... I *am* assuming that the meaning here is supposed to be  *very, very* rather than rugged, angular).  To show that this is a cohesive unit (rather than *spiral attractive*), the gluing effect of a hyphen is best employed. Also, scare-italics for a nonce usage. And a clue to the intended meaning.

**He's *Fibonacci-spiral* attractive.**