# Long-term or Long Term?

Tags: american-english, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

I'm creating signage for "Long-term Ventilation Unit" and am keeping it as how I just wrote it. But when Googling, I became slightly confused on whether it is "Long Term Ventilation Unit" or the way I wrote it is just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to hyphenate with compound premodifiers? If so, where is the hyphen placed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/is-it-correct-to-hyphenate-with-compound-premodifiers-if-so-where-is-the-hyphe) << File-system related job vs File system related job, etc. >> One can check first whether _long term_ is preferred with the hyphen when prenominal, in dictionaries.

Comment: There is no consistency in hyphenation practices, so looking on the internet will produce even more confusion. Do what you think is right; that's what everybody else does.

Answer (score 2):

Compound adjectives can be hyphenated to remove ambiguity, or open when there is no ambiguity.

The **potential** ambiguity is that you have a "Long Term-Ventilation Unit": a long unit for ventilating terms. Since that seems improbable, the meaning is far more likely that you have a ventilation unit available for a long term.

However, all ambiguity can be removed by adding the hyphen in the right place. It's not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here, "Long-term Ventilation Unit" looks right; "Long term Ventilation Unit" is occasionally seen, but that can be a bit ambiguous.

The Main Point is that "long term" has adjective "long" acting on "term", whereas "long-term" is itself the adjective acting on the following noun.

Hence, "long-term" is right in your case.