# How should I punctuate a phrasal adjective with additional adjective before the noun?

Tags: phrases, adjectives, commas, hyphenation, compound-adjectives

I am trying to discover the correct hyphenation and/or comma placement for the following sentence relating to honey bees:

> *When she hatches out of her egg, she is placed into a royal jelly filled hexagon cell called a queen’s cup.*

I am inclined to punctuate as follows, but don't know if this is correct or why:

> *When she hatches out of her egg, she is placed into a royal-jelly-filled, hexagon cell called a queen’s cup.*

If it is correct, can someone explain why?  I believe the royal-jelly-filled part should be hyphenated because those words are related and would modify "cell."  However, I am not as sure about placing the comma before "hexagon" or what the rule would be there, since it is an additional modifier of "cell."

I was previously pointed toward this post:

However, the examples in that post all seem to follow the two, or three word compound modifying the noun, such as brick-oven pizza or file-system-related software.   In my case, I've got a fourth, unrelated modifier to deal with.

If my sentence were simply "When she hatches out of her egg, she is placed into a royal-jelly-filled cell called a queen’s cup" I would be satisfied with the hyphenation where I've placed it.

However, my sentence is actually:

> When she hatches out of her egg, she is placed into a royal jelly filled hexagon cell called a queen’s cup.

Royal-jelly-filled is related.  Hexagon is not.  It's a separate adjective to describe the cell.   Royal-jelly-filled-hexagon does not seem correct, so where then, does the hyphenation end?  Does a comma belong after "filled"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to hyphenate with compound premodifiers? If so, where is the hyphen placed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/is-it-correct-to-hyphenate-with-compound-premodifiers-if-so-where-is-the-hyphe) While J D OConal's answer (after Fowler?) would suggest << royal-jelly-filled hexagon cell >>, << file-system–related software >> (in the most upvoted answer) suggests << royal-jelly–filled hexagon cell >> (treating 'hexagon cell' as a compound).

Comment: Per @EdwinAshworth, the royal-jelly-filled part modifes hexagon cell, not cell alone. So the comma goes. Or reword it.

Comment: "Royal-jelly-filled is related." That's not how I read it; it made more sense to me for "royal" to modify "cell" and not "jelly" or "jelly-filled". However, I don't know anything about bees, so your interpretation certainly may be correct.

Comment: Isn't it a hexagonal cell and not the cell of a hexagon as your current wording implies?

Comment: @tchrist 'Hexagon cell' is not unattested.  Though not as well as 'Octagon Theatre'.

Comment: @Barmar Got it, thanks! I recommend that OP include that information in the question, as it helps to explain why "royal-jelly-filled" should be hyphenated as a single compound.