# "Company-assigned" or "company assigned"

Tags: hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it appropriate to use a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12494/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-a-hyphen)

In phrases describing something that has been assigned to someone, should the phrase be hyphenated or not?

```
He uses a company-assigned phone number.
```

or

```
He uses a company assigned phone number.
```

What is the rule for similar phrases?

Comment: Related: [Should I use “ related” or “-related”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/should-i-use-related-or-related); [When is it appropriate to use a hyphen?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12494/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-a-hyphen); [Chainsaw-equipped or chainsaw equipped?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4761/chainsaw-equipped-or-chainsaw-equipped)

Comment: The general rule is that adjective phrases (phrases used as adjectives) should be hyphenated. So, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sentence is made clearer by the hyphenation, then it's a good idea.

In a case where you use several adjectives, it may help to identify which are being 'combined'.

For example 'use three two digit numbers' is a little clearer as 'use three two-digit numbers'