# "on time" vs. "on-time"

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation

I'm in the "on-time" camp when it comes to describing, for example, delivering something by the deadline. Is this the correct usage?

Comment: Are you specifically referring to using it more as an adjective, e.g. `We provide on-time delivery` or also something like `We will deliver it on time`?

Comment: if you can differentiate between the two, that would be ideal.

Comment: Dusty has the answer. You hyphenate when you combine the two-words as a compound adjective before a noun. When you use it as an adverbial phrase, you don't.

Comment: @Dusty @Robusto -- I'm with Jason on this one. There's still something missing, here.  For example, for `We provide late delivery` and `We will deliver it late`, we didn't have to change `late` into anything else, how come?

Comment: @BeemerGuy because late is the same in adjective and adverb forms.  Try the following: `We provide careful delivery` vs. `We will deliver it carefully`.

Comment: @Dusty -- ok that clears it along with your **on-point** answer below (see, I used the hyphen correctly =)) Thanks.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/should-i-use-related-or-related

Comment: @cerberus this is in no way related to that question.

Comment: @Jason: Why not? By the way, it is all right to ask a duplicate question, this was not meant as criticism; I was just identifying and linking them. There are several more duplicates of this question. They all ask about the use of hyphens in compound adjectives.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In a situation where you're using the phrase `on time` as an adjective (basically a synonym of punctual) preceding the noun, then it's fairly common to use a hyphen.  Examples I was able to quickly pull up were things like

> On-time delivery is our goal.
>
> On-time flight departures were up 10%.
>
> On-time performance is an important ingredient

However, if you're using the phrase `on time` as an adverb to describe when the verb is going to happen, the hyphen is not appropriate.  For example:

> We will deliver your package on time.
>
> Your flight will depart on time.

Finally, if you're using `on time` as a predicate adjective, I would not use the hyphen.

> Your delivery was on time.

Answer (score 4):

When a multiword phrase is used as an adjective, then you use hyphens to join up the words. Otherwise you don’t.

> We provide on-time delivery.

Hyphen because *on-time* is used as an adjective modifying *delivery*

> We will deliver it on time.

No hyphen because it is used as an ordinary idiomatic prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 1):

#### Adverbial phrase: *on time*

This describes the punctual manner in which an action is undertaken. Examples:

- ```
  My package was delivered on time.
  ```
- ```
  Did he arrive on time?
  ```
- ```
  Am I on time?
  ```

#### Adjective: *on-time*?

My guess is that this usage is informal. Certainly it is possible to hyphenate words to convert them into adjectives. A good example is the noun *cutting edge*, which can be used as an adjective thus:

- ```
  MIT is a hot spot for cutting-edge physics.
  ```

*on time* is special, as it is an adverb, but it is not uncommon to see it as an adjective thus:

- ```
  We give you on-time solutions to your problems.
  ```

I find that this sort of usage occurs mostly in marketing, especially in the delivery business. As a personal matter of taste, I would substitute *on-time* with other established adjectives in formal writing. Examine the following sentences:

- ```
   We offer on-time deliveries.
  ```
- ```
   We offer prompt deliveries.
  ```
- ```
   Our deliveries are on time.
  ```

I would prefer the second to the first for formality's sake. The third sentence, however, is perfectly fine and acceptable in all situations. It is important to recognize where *on time* is used as an adverb, in order to avoid incorrect hyphenation. This is a mistake I imagine is commonly made.