# Is it correct to write "a 5-mm-thick layer"?

Tags: writing, adjectives, articles, hyphenation, modifiers

Do I need hyphens? Should I use the indefinite article or zero article?

Comment: This question may be relevant as well: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/should-i-use-related-or-related

Comment: Closely related to: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1366/2085

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is incorrect to write "a 5-mm-thick layer". Rather, it should be written:

> a 5 mm-thick layer

or, better,

> a five millimeter-thick layer

*5 mm-thick* is a compound adjective formed from the adjectives *5 mm* and *thick*, and it modifies *layer*. Consider:

> - a *5-mm* layer/a *5 mm* layer
>     (*as a matter of style, some writers don't hyphenate numerals with letters*)
> - a *five-millimeter* layer
> - a *thick* layer
> - a *5 mm-thick* layer

Note that as a compound adjective in its own right, *5-mm/five-millimeter* is hyphenated. When compounded again, though, the first hyphen is dropped: *5 mm-long/five millimeter-wide*, etc.

Other similar compound adjectives can be found in contexts similar to the following:

> - a *five year-long* period
> - a *two month-old* movie
> - a *ten year-old* boy

Review this [article](http://www.kentlaw.edu/academics/lrw/grinker/LwtaCompound_Adjectives.htm) for more on compound adjectives.

Comment: I'm surprised that a prescriptive rule (I note that no authority is mentioned) requires a ten year-old boy rather than a ten-year-old boy. Certainly _Ten year-old boys were monitored for signs of the condition_ is different from _Ten-year-old boys were monitored_ ... . The best criterion to apply is surely the avoidance of ambiguity. Wikipedia, in a fine article at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen , addresses this consideration, and the relaxing of overly precious demands for pet styles of hyphenating.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  You’re right, and I am pretty sure this answer is wrong.  See my own.

Comment: Structurally OP's example is no different to ["five year old boy"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22five+year+old+boy%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), where skimming through some of the hundreds of thousands of examples in that Google Books link, it's quite clear the vast majority use **two** hyphens. Even if this answer is "correct" according to some particular style guide (I see none cited) it's obviously out of step with majority usage. In short, it's ***wrong***.

Answer (score 14):

To answer the question directly: yes, it is perfectly correct to write “a 5-mm-thick layer”.  However, when not in prefix position, it would be “a layer that’s 5 mm thick”, this time without any hyphens.

The accepted answer appears to be wrong in its assertion that there is something wrong with writing “a five-millimeter-thick layer”.   There isn’t.

Here are actual examples:

- This will be squeezed into a one-foot-thick ice layer in a century or two. . . . [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=NejNlqN2vj8C&pg=PA36&dq=foot+thick&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ecyfUOyrKvDlyAHO2YGwBw&ved=0CGoQ6AEwDw#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- That layer, in turn, is underlain by a 6- to 9-mile-thick layer of extremely dense rock that is even more iron-rich than the basalt on the surface.  [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=eDU3P-Qy6akC&pg=PA43&dq=mile+thick&hl=en&sa=X&ei=a8-fUNmhN6fRyQHmv4CwBA&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- Here the phosphatic rocks are 14.9 feet thick, and a 5.8-foot-thick zone has an average of 22.1 percent P2O5. [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=nccKAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA81&dq=foot+thick&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ecyfUOyrKvDlyAHO2YGwBw&ved=0CHkQ6AEwFA#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- The first rapids, just above the Rice River confluence, rates class I. Just downstream from the confluence, the Little Fork flows through a 50-yard-long rapids, flanked by outcrops, which bends sharply left and throws 2-foot waves in high water. [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=7Dv_-k3G-3YC&pg=PA44&dq=yard+long&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-dCfUM6BG6HYywGh6oD4Ag&ved=0CGQQ6AEwEDgy#v=onepage&q=yard%20long&f=false)
- The Dakota Sandstone consists of three distinct stratigraphic units: (1) a 4- to 134-foot-thick, lower conglomeratic. . . . [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=bCxVcqeevzEC&pg=PA8&dq=foot+thick&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vc2fULzCE8egyAHh8YHACg&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBjgy#v=onepage&q=foot%20thick&f=false)
- Starting at the bend of the hook, tie in the white thread and a sparse bunch of 3-inch-long white bucktail. [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=LOFDXjrLkvAC&pg=PA47&dq=inch+long&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UtCfUKn2FqfRyQHmv4CwBA&ved=0CJABEOgBMCA#v=onepage&q=inch%20long&f=false)
- Tensile strength of lumber laminated from 1/8-inch-thick veneers (title) [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=TNiaKO0pooEC&q=inch+thick&dq=inch+thick&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Zs6fUNPKLYLaygGXh4DICQ&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ)
- Finally, the cylindrical shaft is comprised of structural walls with a 15.5-foot interior core diameter and that increase in thickness from 27 inches to 33 inches halfway along its 74 foot vertical length, coming to rest on a 20-foot-thick rectangular. . . . [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=rqIay255ad0C&pg=PA80&dq=foot+thick&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vc2fULzCE8egyAHh8YHACg&ved=0CLwBEOgBMCs4Mg#v=onepage&q=foot%20thick&f=false)
- I plod step by ponderous step along the bottom of the 37-foot-deep test tank at NASA's National Space Technology. . . . [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=vn0-Z6cLphgC&pg=PA82&dq=foot-deep&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ftGfUOeuJ5G6yAGr0YHwBw&ved=0CHQQ6AEwFg#v=onepage&q=foot-deep&f=false)
- A twenty-thousand-foot-thick layer of stratified sediments was deposited in a shallow sea over millions of years, creating the Long Island Platform that underlies Long Island. [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=X7xYt7pTjwAC&pg=PA43&dq=foot+thick&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vc2fULzCE8egyAHh8YHACg&ved=0CMUBEOgBMC44Mg#v=onepage&q=foot%20thick&f=false)
- We were sitting under a six-yard-thick concrete ceiling in a nuclear-bomb-proof bunker, and only the vibrations enabled us to guess whether the missiles had landed nearby or farther away. [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=fvOsgQG6NnkC&pg=PA224&dq=yard+thick&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Os-fUNrgGciByAG53IGoCw&ved=0CLEBEOgBMCg4Mg#v=onepage&q=yard%20thick&f=false)
- In the eastern Thousand Lakes Wilderness, about a dozen cinder cones erupted along a 7-mile-long line (perhaps a fault). [. . .] Quarter-mile-thick glaciers flowed through, exerting great pressure on the valley floor. [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=0PTwfnCkpXQC&pg=PA16&dq=mile+thick&hl=en&sa=X&ei=a8-fUNmhN6fRyQHmv4CwBA&ved=0CJEBEOgBMB0#v=onepage&q=mile%20thick&f=false)
- A 4- to 6-inch-tall species with 5- to 6-inch-long leaves that are about 1 inch wide. [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=557KJL0TC48C&pg=PA151&dq=A+4-+to+6-inch-+tall+species+with+5-+to+6-inch-long+leaves+that+are+about+1+inch+wide.&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6dKfUI2-JefIyQGOroC4Bw&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=A%204-%20to%206-inch-%20tall%20species%20with%205-%20to%206-inch-long%20leaves%20that%20are%20about%201%20inch%20wide.&f=false)

  **NOTE:** There are many, many examples at that citation, several dozen on the referenced page alone:
  [image: more examples]
- While the main gun rounds of the M60A1 remain unprotected in this picture, the main gun rounds in the M1 are protected by one-inch-thick blast doors, which are closed in this image. [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=M1P6jT8_yrgC&pg=PA102&dq=inch+thick&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Zs6fUNPKLYLaygGXh4DICQ&ved=0CKUBEOgBMCY#v=onepage&q=inch%20thick&f=false)
  [image: more examples]

I believe that should establish the “correctness” of the fully hyphenated form. Certainly it occurs with plenty of frequency in written English, although  I cannot speak to non-English usage.

Comment: Per my comment to the (incorrect) accepted answer, I think this is one of those cases where citing authorities/style guides isn't really necessary. Actual usage so overwhelmingly favours using ***both*** hyphens it would be meaningless to claim that's somehow "wrong".

Comment: Really? A quick (but adjusted for repeats) Google search for "mm thick layer" shows a preponderence of non-hyphenated forms, followed some way behind by the doubly-hyphenated. Interestingly, one source ( www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/ ...) uses both alternatives.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [Yes, really](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=six+-+inch+-+thick%2Csix+inch+thick&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).  Now try with “six-mile-long”, “three-foot-wide”, etc.  The hyphenated forms clearly dominate, and often eclipse.

Comment: [Two-inch-thick layer](http://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&hs=shz&tbo=d&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1631&bih=1081&tbm=bks&q=%22two-inch-thick+layer%22&oq=%22two-inch-thick+layer%22&gs_l=serp.3...0.0.0.777082.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.5IUcielJM0E): **18** × "two-inch-thick layer" + **27** × "two-inch thick layer" + **7** × "two inch thick layer".  Run the same on ***"2-inch-thick layer"*** and you get **27** × "2-inch-thick layer" + **6** × "two-inch thick layer" + **10** × "two inch thick layer". See what I mean now?

Comment: tchrist, Sometimes there is safety in numbers. But i wouldn't place too much confidence in your list of citations demonstrating first-hyphen preservation in multi compound-adjective terms. You cite McClelland & Steward (Concrete Toronto), who, in the same passage, use "comprised of". This doesn't prove anything either way about hyphenating of course. I am, however, under the impression that the first hyphen gets dropped when a compound adjective is joined by another adjective.

Answer (score 1):

According to excerpts from the Chicago Manual of Style, 5-mm-thick layer is correct: 
http://www.apsstylemanual.org/oldmanual/mechanics/hyphens.htm
http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf

Comment: We like references, but you should quote the relevant parts in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would have said that there is no need for a hyphen between 5 and mm; 5mm is normally written thus.

So it would be:

> A 5mm-thick layer.

Comment: The [SI brochure](http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/chapter5/5-3-2.html "BIPM") mandates a space between the number and the unit, so it should be _5 mm_ rather than _5mm_.