# Three part or Three-part

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a grammar rule behind the hyphen in the phrase 'one-act play'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9549/is-there-a-grammar-rule-behind-the-hyphen-in-the-phrase-one-act-play)

Okay, so it might sound like a primitive question. However, I can find out a reasoning or maybe which form is correct.

The sentence is

> This is a three parts series.

I'm not sure if I should add the delimiter or not; and maybe there is a possession "'s", and I'm not quite sure of that. So any help with explanation would be great!

Comment: *three-part* is a compound adjective describing *series*.

Comment: There is no possession. Unless it's *your* three-part series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write it like this:

> This is a three-part series.

No s, with a hyphen. As for why, when you put a compound adjectival phrase (like *three-part*) in front of a noun, you hyphenate it.