# Singular or plural form of property, when describing an object with N-count for the property

Tags: grammatical-number

Is the singular or plural form of a property required when describing an object which has a count of N for that property?

For example, a two-mode or a two-modes analog filter?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but your example would normally be referred to as a "two-**mode** analog filter".  Other examples could be  "five-speed gearbox", "four-horse sleigh" or "two-party system".

Comment: That's the question :) Whether you should say "five-speeds gearbox" or "five-speed gearbox", "four-horses sleigh" or "four-horse sleigh" etc.

Comment: Well then my comment has answered your question.

Comment: Indeed, you are welcome to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Lawler coined the [Eleven-year-old boy rule](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/209603/15299) which is also mentioned in [another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76247/a-place-nearby-but-not-a-place-good).

The general rule is that one-word modifiers precede the noun; modifiers of more than one word follow the noun.

Here, you are using a hyphen to make a one-word modifier ("two-mode") so it goes before the noun, as you have it. It's an adjective, describing your analogue filter.

**Adjectives are never inflected for number in English.**

Note that foreign adjectives in English *are* often inflected for number, like *beaux arts* — but that's not English. English adjectives (**red** apple/**red** apples) don't change. They are always expressed in a singular form.

Because adjectives are never inflected for number, the correct form is *two-mode.*

---

<sub>This question is a good, generalised question on the subject which we haven't had before. It can serve as a destination for duplicates, and we need an explicitly explanatory answer.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You would say "two-mode analog filter".

Other examples could be "five-speed gearbox", "four-horse sleigh" or "two-party system".