# 6 week course or 6-week course

Tags: grammar, phrases

I know that this question may be a bit trivial but just curious about it.

I know that according to grammar, “six-week course” is the right form. But when I replace “six” with the number 6, I read that both “6 week course” and “6-week course” are pretty common, so a bit confused about which is grammarly correct and which may be better.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do we hyphenate adjectives including numbers?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/479109/do-we-hyphenate-adjectives-including-numbers)

Comment: @WeatherVane It does now I've included the bit about stylistic representation of numbers.