# I see lots of examples of unnecessary hyphenation in phrases like "when she was five-years-old", is there a change in usage, or is it technology?

Tags: hyphenation

Obviously, at least to me as a native speaker, *"when she was five years old"* doesn't need any hyphens, any more than *"when she was five feet tall"* or *"when she had long black hair"*, but I'm seeing the hyphens used in lots of online writing, for example [this article](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/03/10/americas/canada-teacher-diaries-returned-trnd/index.html) has

> He never read the diaries, but he held on to them so that he could return them at graduation and have his students look back at what they were like at 12-years-old.

Again, my instinct as a native speaker is that we only need the hyphens when we make "five years old" into an adjective: "she was a five-year-old child".

Someone has suggested to me that it may be some grammar checker, like Microsoft Word, offering it erroneously as a grammar change. But surely journalists for major online outlets aren't writing in Word, and aren't taking its grammar suggestions if they do? Also my version of Word doesn't suggest any change to "five years old" when I run a grammar check.

Comment: I tried to prove this was happening with the Google Ngram viewer but it doesn't register punctuation as far as I can see, and responds to hyphens as minus signs for some other purpose.

Comment: hypercorrection

Comment: "surely journalists for major online outlets aren't writing in Word, and aren't taking its grammar suggestions if they do?" - don't bank on that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do we hyphenate adjectives including numbers?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/479109/do-we-hyphenate-adjectives-including-numbers)

Comment: I think that journalists at major news organizations using Word’s suggestions is a very likely answer to this. Journalists are notoriously susceptible to all sorts of foolish ideas so this explanation would fit right in.