# "Resigned manager" vs "Stepped-down manager"

Tags: word-choice

Which one of the following adjectives is the right one to describe someone who has just stepped down as a manager?

- "Resigned manager"
- "Stepped-down manager"

Comment: Any wording that forces you to reread it 3 times needs improvement. In this case, ex-manager is okay, but that manager who ... is just right.

Comment: *Resigned* as an adjective has a very different meaning. *Stepped down* as an adjective suggests either a lowered voltage or a garden feature.

Comment: I know how someone can be resigned to some action or fate,  but how do you step them down?

Answer (score 1):

Neither *resigned* nor *stepped-down* is an adjective. And neither is used attributively (before a noun phrase being modified). As to choosing between

> the manager who resigned

and

> the manager who stepped down,

the choice depends on context and precise meaning. *Resign* means leave an organization’s employment altogether, whereas *step down* can mean that, but can also mean leave one position in favor of another one, typically of lower rank.

If one doesn’t choose to make that distinction, then, as @Yosef Baskin has commented, *ex-manager* is fine.

Comment: “Former manager” also works.  Or you can use something like “X, until recently the manager of . . . “

Comment: @Xanne, mind if I fold *former manager* into my answer?

Comment: Although this is a bit nitpicking, a senior manager who has 'stepped down' to be a junior manager is neither a *former manager* nor an *ex manager*.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum That would be fine!

Comment: 'Resigned' _is_ an adjective, but often not with the sense needed here. And it can be used in combination prenominally with the required sense: _... the recently resigned Director-General of RTÉ, Dee Forbes_ ...'. The ['Eleven-year-old boy Rule'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209594/a-turned-on-or-off-car/209603#209603), as mentioned by J Lawler.